# How can I rearrange a Pandas DataFrame containing a list of coordinates into a table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of coordinates in the form

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X1 | Y1 | Z (X1,Y1) |
| X1 | Y2 | Z (X1,Y2) |
| ... | ... | ... |
| X1 | YN | Z (X1,YN) |
| X2 | Y1 | Z (X2,Y1) |
| X2 | Y2 | Z (X2,Y1) |
| ... | ... | ... |
| XN | YN | Z (XN,YN) |

I needed to do it this way because the function of Z was finicky.

Matplot lib needs the Z values in is a 2D array. I want to rearragne the table such that:

|  | Y1 | Y2 | ... | YN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X1 | X(X1,Y1) | Z(X1, Y2) | ... | Z(X1, YN) |
| X2 | Z(X2, Y1) | Z(X2, Y2) | ... | Z(X2, YN) |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| XN | Z(XN, Y1) | Z(XN, Y2) | ... | Z(XN, YN) |

I've tried a few pivot options in Pandas, but no luck. Iterating through the table is proving unreliable.

I'm lost, please help.

**Edit:** `plotable_table = table.pivot(index = 'X', columns = 'Y', values = 'Z') returns something odd. Unfortunately table is a 3 x 230 and plotable_table is 23 x 142.... It should be 23 x 10

**table is :**

```
         X         Y        Z
0     10000       0.0      0.0
1     10000    1000.0   -200.6
2     10000    2000.0   -401.2
3     10000    3000.0   -601.8
4     10000    4000.0   -802.4
..      ...       ...      ...
225  230000  115000.0  -9050.5
226  230000  138000.0 -26726.0
227  230000  161000.0 -56028.0
228  230000  184000.0 -66562.0
229  230000  207000.0 -77096.0
    [230 rows x 3 columns]
```

**plotable table is:**

```
Y       0.0       1000.0    2000.0    ...  189000.0  198000.0  207000.0
X                                     ...
10000        0.0    -200.6    -401.2  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN    
20000        0.0       NaN    -401.2  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN    
30000        0.0       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN    
40000        0.0       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN    
50000     4070.0       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN    
60000     4884.0       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN    
70000     5698.0       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN    
80000     6512.0       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN    
90000     9846.0       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN    
100000   18230.0       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN    
110000   20053.0       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN    
120000   24768.0       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN    
130000   26832.0       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN    
140000   28896.0       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN    
150000   30960.0       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN    
160000   41184.0       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN    
170000   43758.0       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN    
180000   46332.0       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN    
190000   48906.0       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN    
200000   51480.0       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN    
210000   54054.0       NaN       NaN  ...  -86562.0       NaN       NaN    
220000   73568.0       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN  -73744.0       NaN    
230000   76912.0       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN  -77096.0 

[23 rows x 142 columns]
```

Comment: the 1st table is pretty confusing.

Comment: I don't understand your pattern in the required output.  It all seems to be functions of z apart from the X(X1,Y1) in the Y1 column.  How does this fit with the rest of the data.

Comment: I'm assuming you're looking for  `df.pivot(index='X', columns='Y', values='Z')`

Comment: Sorry! @PaulBrennan there was typo in the table. In first table I am basically iterating over all the combinations of x and y by going through each x and multiplying it by the array of y's.

Comment: Try `df.pivot(index='foo', columns='bar', values='Z')`

Comment: @Chris plotable_table = table.pivot(index = 0, columns =1, values = 2) was my first attempt. Table is first table here and 0, 1, 2 are the first through third columns. 

Unfortunately table is a 3 x 230 and plotable_table is 23x142.... It should be 23x10

Comment: @FLAV10 you should use the sintax that Chris provided, not using integers as you show

Comment: @DavidFelipeMedinaMayorga I set the columns so X Y Z are the labels. and tried with the sintax chris provided. the output looks the output in the edited question. 

THANK YOU ALL FOR YOUR HELP BY THE WAY <3

Comment: Did you see how many distinct values are for X and Y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for this is:

```
data = data.pivot(index='X', columns='Y', values='Z')
```

The dimensions of your pivot table depends of the unique values of X and Y. You should count how many distinct values you have for Y.

Comment: I think you're right. The Y values are simply a percentage of X ..  np.arange(0,1,0.1) I suspect there's a floating point thing making the Y values non-unique ex: 2 and 2.000000004. 

Give me a moment to investigate! Thanks for putting me on the right path :)

Comment: @FLAV10 No problem. Try to round by 0 - 2 decimal positions.